# Set cell width in knitr/pandoc?

Tags: html, css, r, knitr

I am generating a HTML file with knitr/pandoc which prints several tables in a loop. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
theme: cosmo
---

```{r results ="asis", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, kable}
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(pander)

for (i in 1:12) {
  df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(i), nrow=2))
  cat(pandoc.table(df, split.table = Inf))
}
```
````

The printed data frames (tables) have a different number of cells, but they all have the same total width.
I tried to set a fixed width with CSS by setting the table width to "auto" and align it left, but I didn't succeed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the `width: 100%` setting in the original CSS. You can override that by using a custom theme or an additional CSS -- e.g. something minimal like this:

```
table {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

The `!important` rule stands for forcing this `width` instead of the original `100%`. Now save this file as e.g. `custom.css` and pass it in the YAML header:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cosmo
    css: custom.css
---
```

And BTW you do not need to `cat` the results of `pander` :)